# Website not using imported Google Font locally but working in codepen

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have a test site that I'm making it doesn't use the imported font or the backup font. The strange thing is that while it doesn't change the font locally, putting the code into codepen works just fine.

In case you're wondering, I have all of my files in the right places (see image)

[image: File structure]

Also, here's the [codepen link](https://codepen.io/overfront64/pen/vYKqXZr) for my source code and it's also here below:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;700&display=swap');
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Test Page</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Test Page" />
  <meta name="author" content="test Page" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <link href="style.css" ref="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <section id="hero">
    <div class="hero container"></div>
    <div>
      <h1>Test Header</h1>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" type="button" class="cta">Test Button</a>
  </section>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its `rel` not `ref` for linking stylesheet

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I didn't notice that! Why did it work on codepen then if it wouldn't work locally?

Comment: @Overfront64 Code pen does not require linking style.css. try removing the link tag, it still works the same